# Is there an emulator for Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: android, android-emulator, galaxy, galaxy-tab

Fair warning: I'm a complete noob to android development

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and want to know if there exists an Android emulator (add-on) for it?  Using the third-party site http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml I get a "Galaxy TAB" add-on but it is for Android 2.2 (API level 8).

Is this the only emulator add-on there is for Galaxy TABs?  The Galaxy 10.1 is runs Android 3.1 and has a different form factor I believe so it seems like there needs to be an emulator for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an emulator with specifics matching the Galaxy Tab 10.1 in the AVD (Android Virtual Device) Manager.

Comment: OK.  So the third-party add-ons are just emulators created by the vendor in the AVD with specific parameters, the same way anyone can create an emulator?

Comment: pretty much yeah. Some have device specific skins, for example the Galaxy TAB addon.